# How to accumulate gradient across mini-batch and then back-propagation in Chainer?

Tags: chainer, chainercv

I am doing classifying video sequence, I need 2 things:

1. Because of limited GPU memory, I want to accumulate gradient across mini-batch, and then average gradient value, and then back propagation.
2. I need to know how to shuffle between mini-batch but not shuffle inside each mini-batch, because I want the video sequence keep its order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1:
You can forward and backward each minibatch but **not call optimizer.update()**, after you have repeated forward & backward for necessary minibatches, you can call **optimizer.update()** to updated based on accumulated gradients.

If you want to achieve it with `trainer` module, I think you need to override `StandardUpdater` to define your own `Updater` class to do above.

Question 2:
Are you using `trainer` module?
If so, you can define your own iterator to achieve this. See also below for reference how to define iterator class.

- https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/examples/ptb/train_ptb.py
- http://corochann.com/training-rnn-with-simple-sequence-dataset-1304.html

Comment: about question 2: the difficult part is how to write such keep_inside_batch_order iterator in Parallel iterator? I mean to use multiple process to parallel fetch data and keep shuffle=False inside mini-batch.?

Comment: Maybe I need to know more concrete situation to answer this question.
Could you provide detail information in new question thread?